# How to use this version: 10.1.3.10-1545tr103f5d format in chocolatey nuspec version

Tags: nuget-package, chocolatey, choco

How to use version: 10.1.3.10-1545tr103f5d format in chocolatey nuspec version. I want to include git commit id with chocolatey package version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you can't.

Chocolatey uses a non-strict semantic version numbering strategy, meaning that it will support 4 part version numbers, but you can't have a structure that is

`major.minor.build.build-number`

What you could do is something like the following:

```
10.1.3.10-g1545tr103f5d
```

Notice the introduction of the `g` after the `-`.  As long as you have a non-digit character here, you should be able to complete the `choco pack` command.